# Android app desktop manipulation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

Is there a way to change the location of the applications on the desktop from a program? I have a script that installs a couple of applications to a Android tablet, but I want to move them to the desktop/dashboard at install time. Is there a manifest file that specifies the desktop layout?

Comment: I don't think you can but someone else might chime in with some cool knowledge.